# problemas con poner elementos en el Html - Javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde tengo que poner "noticia nacional" o "noticia internacional",dependiendo si la noticia es nacional o internacional, el problema es que le aplico un display none al texto de "noticia nacional" o "noticia internacional" correspondiente, pero solo hace efecto en el primer section, ya lo he intentado de varias maneras pero la verdad no se porque no hace efecto

aca una imgaen de la pagina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca dejo el codigo JavaScript:

```
let contenedorNoticias= document.querySelector(".general");


for (let i = 0; i < noticias.length; i++) {
    let plantillaNotica= `
        <section class="sec1">
            <div>
                <img src="${noticias[i].imgUrl}">
            </div>

            <div class="tipoNoticia">
                <p>Noticia Internacional</p>
                <p>Noticia Nacional</p>
            </div>
        
            <div>
                <h2>${noticias[i].titulo}</h2>
                <p>${noticias[i].fecha}</p>
                <p>${noticias[i].descripcion}</p>
            </div>
        </section >       
    `
    
    contenedorNoticias.innerHTML += plantillaNotica

    const contenedorNoticia= document.querySelectorAll(".sec1");
    const tipoNoticia = document.querySelector('.tipoNoticia')

    if(noticias[i].tipoNacional == true) {
        contenedorNoticia[i].classList.add('noticiaNacional') 
        tipoNoticia.children[0].style.display = "none"     
        console.log(tipoNoticia.children[0])   
    }
}
```

Comment: Podría editar la pregunta y colocar el código HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un operador ternario, para mostrar uno u otro:

```
let plantillaNotica= `
        <section class="sec1 ${noticias[i].tipoNacional?'noticiaNacional':''}">
            <div>
                <img src="${noticias[i].imgUrl}">
            </div>

            <div class="tipoNoticia">
                ${noticias[i].tipoNacional?'<p>Noticia Nacional</p>':'<p>Noticia Internacional</p>'}
                
            </div>
        
            <div>
                <h2>${noticias[i].titulo}</h2>
                <p>${noticias[i].fecha}</p>
                <p>${noticias[i].descripcion}</p>
            </div>
        </section >       
    `;
```